# Is there any way to automatically decrease subwoofer volume at night?

Tags: linux, windows, audio, speakers

I'm using both Windows and Ubuntu, so a solution for either (or both!) would be great!

---

I live in an apartment complex, and love to listen to bassy music and watch movies. My neighbors are fine with this during the day, but not at night. **Is there a program that will automatically lower just my subwoofer's volume at night (or transition between equalizer settings at certain times of day)**, in much the same way f.lux manages my displays' white points?

Comment: How are the speakers connected to your system? Are they even capable of being controlled by software?

Comment: @Karan through 3 3-pole 3.5mm audio ports on the motherboard. The default drivers easily separate each speaker, so I'm currently manually turning down the subwoofer at night. http://i.imgur.com/NYdxpXP.png

Answer (score 2):

1. Download [**NirCmd**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) (it's portable).
2. On the `Control Panel > Sound > Playback tab` check what your default playback device is called. By default it is "Speakers", but in your case it seems to be "5.1 Speakers" (you can always rename it on the *General* tab of the device's *Properties* page).
3. Right-click the default playback device, click on *Properties*, then go to the *Levels* tab and check what you specifically want to control the volume of. In your case it is "Subwoofer":

   [image: 1]
4. See if the [setsubunitvolumedb](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/setsubunitvolumedb.html) command works:

   ```
   nircmd setsubunitvolumedb "5.1 Speakers" "Subwoofer" -10
   ```

   > setsubunitvolumedb [Device Name] [Subunit Name] [Decibel Value]
   >
   > Set the sound volume (in Decibels) of sound device subunit.
   >
   > The [Device Name] is the name of the device, as appeared in the sound
   >   devices list of windows. In most cases the device name is 'Speakers'.
   >
   > The [Subunit Name] is the name of a subunit, as appeared in the
   >   'Level' tab of the device properties window. Examples for subunit
   >   name: Phone Line, Microphone, Internal MIC, Line In, and so on...
5. If it does, you can simply create a couple of shortcuts to NirCmd.exe (for increasing and decreasing volume) with the appropriate parameters added to the *Target* fields. You can also create a couple of scheduled tasks that run NirCmd.exe automatically with the appropriate parameters twice a day - once in the morning to increase and again in the evening to decrease the volume.

---

**Edit:** Ok, this should work no matter what sound card you have.

1. Download [**SoundVolumeView**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html) (it's portable too).

   [image: 2]
2. Set the volume levels you want for morning and save them to a profile named (for example) **Morning_Profile.spr**. Similarly create an **Evening_Profile.spr** with the required volume levels for each sound component.
3. Now you can use `SoundVolumeView /LoadProfile [Filename]` to load the profile you want (create shortcuts or scheduled tasks as required).
4. You can also directly set the volume of the subwoofer using `SoundVolumeView /SetVolume [Name or Item ID] [Volume]`. Name or Item ID for the subwoofer can be noted from the respective columns in the program, and Volume is a number between 0 and 100.

Comment: Also see [mutesubunitvolume](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/mutesubunitvolume.html).

Comment: The command you quoted isn't changing the volume level. Also, nothing is output, so I don't know if something went wrong. I'm feeling a message was sent nowhere.

Comment: So the subwoofer volume didn't change at all? If you change the device name from "5.1 Speakers" to just "Speakers" and also the command accordingly, does that help? Otherwise NirCmd may just not be able to interface with the speaker-specific volume sliders that the driver displays.

Comment: Changing the name and command did not work; the outcome is the same.

Comment: Then possibly the only way to automate this will be to create a complex AutoHotkey script. :( Edit: If you use Process Monitor while changing the subwoofer's volume, can you figure out which registry key the setting is saved to?

Comment: I'm sure other/custom drivers would be a much better solution, especially since such a script would do terrible things, such as interrupt video playback, catch my actual keystrokes, fail due to assumed circumstances or poor timing, etc.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what `nircmd showsounddevices` shows?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/cOFjgID.png

Comment: See if the edit above helps you.

Comment: How do I automate that so it applies the profiles every morning and evening? Also, when I right-click Subwoofer and click mute, nothing actually happens aside from the icons changing.

Comment: Just create a scheduled task that invokes `SoundVolumeView /LoadProfile [Filename]` at the time you want. Regarding muting the subwoofer, if that doesn't work with your setup for some reason then just save a profile with the subwoofer volume set to 0.