# Win-F4 does not mute or unmute microphone during Lync converstation

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, microphone, lync-2010

I am using Lync 2010, and need to mute/unmute my microphone frequently during the conversation. Searching on the web, I found that the the global shortcut Win-F4 should do this, but it seems having no any effect. Other keyboard shortcuts seem working on Lync, and Lync can be muted-unmuted by clicking with the mouse on the mute button in GUI (too slow as the mouse pointer must be moved to that button first).

In case Lync 2010 does not support muting by the Win-F4 shortcut, please provide possible alternative solution for muting the microphone through the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MicMute](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Other-AUDIO-Tools/Poryvaev-MicMute.shtml) does exactly that is required. Unlike `nircmd` solutions, it allows to see the current status of the microphone in the task bar. I have assigned the mute function to the seldom used key on the keyboard.

It is also possible to mute through the control dialog accessible from the speaker icon context menu (recording devices > select mic > properties > levels). Nicely working button shows up there, but you need quite a long way to navigate to see this button; this must be done in advance before the meeting.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shortcut to [**NirCmd**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) that does this. Add the following to the *Target* of the shortcut:

1. Using [**muteappvolume**](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/muteappvolume.html):

   ```
   <path to nircmd.exe> muteappvolume Lync.exe 2 Microphone
   ```
2. Using [**mutesysvolume**](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/mutesysvolume.html):

   ```
   <path to nircmd.exe> mutesysvolume 2 Microphone
   ```

Note: Use the correct executable name if it isn't *Lync.exe*, and also the correct name for your microphone (visible by right-clicking the volume icon and clicking on *Recording devices*).

In the rare case when neither of these works for you, **SoundVolumeView** will for sure as I've described [here](https://superuser.com/a/906208/138343).

Comment: I have downloaded nircmd.exe, The second approach works.